# EmberJS model hook: this.store.find returns no data. How do I redirect to a 404 page?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

When my path `/map/:id` finds no value via `this.store.find('location', route.id)`, I'd like to redirect to another page instead of receiving an `"adapter's response did not have any data"` error. It seems to stop processing before it even gets to the controller.

I thought the best way to do this was to extend `DS.FixtureAdapter` or to return a proxy object until `this.store.find` resolves. I read the documentation and it said to extend `DS.FixtureAdapter` via `find` or `findMany` hooks, among others. When I tried, none of the events seemed to fire, and I can't figure out an appropriate alternative return object. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.store.find()` returns a promise. Promise resolution has 2 outcomes: 1. good and 2. bad. You can pass in 2 functions into the `then()` method to tell a promise what to do in each scenario.

So, let's say you are looking for a record and it's not there (bad outcome), you can tell ember to transition to another route.

```
App.DudeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var route = this;
    return this.store.find('dude', 5).then(
      function(dude){
        return dude; 
      }, 
      function(error){
        route.transitionTo('nomansland');
      }); 
  }
});
```

Also note that you need to create a `route` variable, because just using `this` inside the bad scenario won't work, since `this` gets a new context.

Working example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lubefe/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: I can't thank you enough, it's working! I got as far as using a `.then()` on the promise, but I looked over creating an error handler (2nd param to `.then()`). Thanks again... huge help.